# Selection of Categorical Features on basis of their values frequency

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on basic Machine Learning Linear Regression Model creation.
I have Categorical Features which are having kind of skewed counts like

```
AllPub    1459
NoSeWa       1
Name: Utilities, dtype: int64
```

As one can see that AllPub is the one which is contributed more. So is it useful in model creation? Shall i use it or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see most of the values are of AllPub, only one value is of NoSeWa. It will not make much difference if you keep or remove. 
Another way of thinking might be a outlier. Since there is count of only one, it might have entered incorrectly. You can impute that value with mode.